# Gunicorn server randomly crashes due to changed working directory

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn

My Gunicorn server is deployed with nginx and has been randomly crashing. After some debugging the only symptom I can identify is that the Gunicorn service's working directory is changing somehow from

`/home/www-user/flask-server/my-site`
to
`/flask-server/my-site`

which of course does not exist and causes problems when using relative paths. My understanding is that Gunicorn/Flask are not able to change their working directory while running. Is this a clue to what could be going wrong?

I've investigated any subprocesses or subroutines that could possibly be failing and somehow changing the directory. I've also added additional logging to try to identify requests that may be causing this. There's no pattern, as far as I can tell the change of working directory happens in between requests (based on the nginx logs)